# Swift - Simple Animation, but requires prolonged hold - Why not tap by default?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, animation

This works like I expected, but I can't just tap it.  I have to hold it for about 3 seconds before it will trigger. I thought maybe it's an issue with table cells so I looked for that as well.

I'll add that I tested with a tagged a UIButton and triggered it with no issue. 
Any thoughts from this group? I just lost the scope of the table and indexPath without a return so....

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.animateIN()

    // set the data into the views

    self.detailNoteDateLabel.text = self.arrayDates[indexPath.row]
    self.detailNoteTextField.text = self.arrayTitles[indexPath.row]
    self.detailNoteTextView.text = self.arrayBody[indexPath.row]
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false


}

func animateIN() {
    //animate the box that shows the note and make it editable
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        //        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        // turn on the dimView/blur
        self.dimView.alpha = 0.7

        //move the view into view
        self.animatedTopConstraint.constant = 35
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        //Fade Into View
        self.detailNotesView.alpha = 1

        }, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to viewDidLoad in your tableView Class:

```
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Comment: No change when I added it. I hoped tho. Thanks.

Comment: Just an update, the issue not resolved. I validated the tableView, and the scrollView it sits in. All are set to false.

Comment: I got around this by using a reuse button to trigger the animation by tag and storing the indexPath in a UIColor.clearColor() titleLabel.  Dirty I'm aware, and so it's marked as workaround in the backlog for removal when I figure this out.